# Sort a list of sting and lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:
`mat = [[1,2,3],"my_nice_list",[1,2,3],"i_am_a_string",[4,5,6]]`

I wan to remove the duplicated nested lists like in the example `[1,2,3]`

So I can have `[[1,2,3],"my_nice_list","i_am_a_string",[4,5,6]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: title is misleading. if I understand correctly you want to remove duplicates not sort a list

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = [[1,2,3],"my_nice_list",[1,2,3],"i_am_a_string",[4,5,6]]
result = []

for i in mat:
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], 'my_nice_list', 'i_am_a_string', [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as list comprehension as well, but it becomes a bit difficult since lists are not hashable, so you have to convert them to tuples and back to lists, but you have to look after the strings doing that:

```
result = [list(y) if not isinstance(y, str) else y for y in set(tuple(x) if not isinstance(x, str) else x for x in mat)]
```

Answer (score -3):

you could try to use this  to remove the duplicates from your list,

```
mat = [[1,2,3],"my_nice_list",[1,2,3],"i_am_a_string",[4,5,6]]

    list1 = []
    for i in mat:
        if i not in list1:
            list1.append(i)
    print(list1)
```

Comment: It is the exact same answer, as @Duarte Castanho gave about 10 minutes before you

Comment: replied before refreshing the page terribly sorry